# Why I cannot find a matrix in the vector space of all $2\times 2$ real matrices that diagonalizes the transpose of rotation matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Let $\theta$ be any real number satisfying $\theta \neq k\pi$ for any integer $k$. Consider the matrix $A\in M_2(\mathbb{R})$ given by

$A=\begin{bmatrix}
\cos\theta & \sin\theta\\
-\sin\theta & \cos\theta
\end{bmatrix}$.

Why is there no matrix in the vector space consisting of all $2\times 2$ matrices that diagonalizes $A$? I have been told, however, that I can find a $2\times 2$ complex matrix that diagonalizes $A$.

Here is what I tried and got stuck:

Suppose there exists a $2\times 2$ real matrix

$B=\begin{bmatrix}
a & b\\
c & d
\end{bmatrix}$

such that

$BA=\begin{bmatrix}
x & 0\\
0 & y
\end{bmatrix}$,

where $x, y\in \mathbb{R}$. Then this implies that
$$a\sin \theta + b \cos \theta =0$$
and
$$c \cos \theta -d \sin \theta =0,$$

or equivalently,
$$(b+c)\cos\theta+(a-d)\sin\theta=0.$$

I have tinkered around with the last few equations above, but have arrived at not a single conclusion. Please help me! Thank you :-)

Comment: Forming $|A - \lambda~I| = 0$, you get the characteristic polynomial $\lambda ^2-2 \lambda  \cos (t)+\sin ^2(t)+\cos ^2(t)$. This means the eigenvalues are $\lambda_{1,2} = \cos (t)~ \pm ~i \sin (t)$. This leads to complex conjugate eigenvectors, $v_{1, 2} = (\mp~ i, 1)$.

Comment: It is unlikely that you have the problem correct. Usually diagonalize would mean $B A B^{-1} = D,$ where $D$ is diagonal. I generally write in the other order, some invertible $C$ such that $C^{-1} A C = D$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that a matrix $B$ *diagonalizes* $A$ if $B^{-1}AB = D$ is diagonal.  Note in particular that this implies that
$$
AB = BD
$$
Let's break $B$ up in terms of its columns and $D$ in terms of its entries: if $B$ has columns $b_1,b_2$ and $D = 
\left(\begin{smallmatrix}d_1&0\\0&d_2 \end{smallmatrix}\right)$, then we can rewrite this as
$$
\pmatrix{A \mathbf b_1 & A \mathbf b_2} = \pmatrix{d_1 \mathbf b_1 & d_2 \mathbf b_2}
$$
as you can verify from the definition of matrix multiplication.  In other words, the columns of $B$ need to be *eigenvectors* of $A$, and the diagonal entries of $D$ need to be *eigenvalues* of $A$.

The question we should ask, then, is this: does $A$ have any real eigenvalues?